# Flask app continuously restarting after downloading huggingface models

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

In my docker container I have a flask app (behind nginx and uwsgi) which instantiates a model from huggingface/transformers.
For some reason, the app continuously restarts when trying to after downloading the models

**App:**

```
### app.py
server = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(server)
server.config["CORS_HEADERS"] = "Content-Type"
log.info("Instantiating model")
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained('dbmdz/bert-large-cased-finetuned-conll03-english')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
pipe = pipeline('ner', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server.run(host=appconf.host, port=appconf.port, debug=appconf.isdev, use_reloader=False)
```

**Logs:**

```
[2020-09-29 14:13:11,704] {./app.py:14} INFO - Instantiating model
[2020-09-29 14:13:11,708] {/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:939} DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): s3.amazonaws.com:443
[2020-09-29 14:13:12,170] {/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:433} DEBUG - https://s3.amazonaws.com:443 "HEAD /models.huggingface.co/bert/dbmdz/bert-large-cased-finetuned-conll03-english/config.json HTTP/1.1" 200 0
[2020-09-29 14:13:12,176] {/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:939} DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): cdn.huggingface.co:443
[2020-09-29 14:13:12,317] {/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:433} DEBUG - https://cdn.huggingface.co:443 "HEAD /dbmdz/bert-large-cased-finetuned-conll03-english/pytorch_model.bin HTTP/1.1" 200 0
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.19.1 (64bit) on [Tue Sep 29 14:13:55 2020] ***
...
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 1727064 bytes (1686 KB) for 16 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
mounting app:server on /
Comment: FROM HERE IT REPEATS
[2020-09-29 14:13:57,254] {./app.py:14} INFO - Instantiating model <-- AGAIN!
[2020-09-29 14:13:57,257] {/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:939} DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): s3.amazonaws.com:443
[2020-09-29 14:13:57,686] {/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:433} DEBUG - https://s3.amazonaws.com:443 "HEAD /models.huggingface.co/bert/dbmdz/bert-large-cased-finetuned-conll03-english/config.json HTTP/1.1" 200 0
[2020-09-29 14:13:57,693] {/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:939} DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): cdn.huggingface.co:443
[2020-09-29 14:13:57,790] {/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:433} DEBUG - https://cdn.huggingface.co:443 "HEAD /dbmdz/bert-large-cased-finetuned-conll03-english/pytorch_model.bin HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

I am sure to have `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` set within the Docker container.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You should download the model during container build, to avoid having to do it on app launch (which is slow and may fail, and rather unkind to the folks at Huggingface who have to pay for the hosting and repeated downloads).

Comment: Please show the uwsgi configuration too – it's very possible that uWSGI doesn't quite like that it takes a long time for the app object to be available after it imports your `app` module.

Comment: When I instantiate the models I am already using `.from_pretrained('name', cache_dir=/path/to/cache/)` (not shown in the code above) so I would have expected that it loads the models from there

Comment: Well, clearly HTTP(S) requests for the models are being made. The cache will work for as long as the container is up (unless you've bind-mounted it or volumed it); when the container restarts, it'd download the data anew, which is unkind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got resolved by increasing the CPU and memory capacity on the server where the container is running.